# JQGrid does not honor autocomplete on multiple filter criteria

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete

I have a JQGrid with multiple headers and two columns with AutoComplete enabled.
When I go to JQGrid Filter and select one of the columns to be filtered with Autocomplete enabled, it works just fine and the Autocomplete function is called as anticipated. However when I add second column for filtering results that also contain Autcomplete functionality, the Autocomplete doesn't work for the new filter and it also disables the auto complete on the previous filter.

This is what the code for AutoComplete looks like:

```
Common.setAutoComplete = function (id, url, select, change, extraParams)
    {
      id.autocomplete(
      {
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            alert("start of autocomplete");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: url,
                data: { query: request.term, extraParameters: extraParams },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data)
                        response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        delay: 10,
        minChars: 1,
        matchSubset: 1,
        matchContains: 1,
        cacheLength: 400,
        select: select,
        change: change,
        autoFill: true
    });
    };
```

And the output from the JQGrid looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var invalidRows = [];
var allRowsValid = true;
var validRows = [];
var IssuerListTablerowId;
var IssuerListTablehasDefaultFilter = true;
var currentTableRowId;
var rowsToSave = [];
var IssuerListTablerowsToSave = [];
var currentTableId = 'IssuerListTable';
     $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#IssuerListTable').jqGrid({

     url:        '/Issuers/GetAll/',
     mtype:      'POST',
     datatype:   'json',
     colNames: ['Issuer', 'ICN', 'Contact', 'Broker'],

     colModel: [
     {"sortable":true, "search":true, "editable":false, "hidden":false, name: 'Name', editrules:{}, addrules:{}, searchoptions: {sopt: ['cn','nc'], searchhidden:true,hidden:false,dataInit:function(a){Common.setAutoComplete($(a),'/Issuers/GetIssuerByShortNameAndLongNameForAutoComplete',null);}} }, 
     {"sortable":true, "search":true, "editable":false, "hidden":false, name: 'ICN', editrules:{}, addrules:{}, searchoptions: {sopt: ['cn','nc'], searchhidden:true,hidden:false} , width: 30}, 
     {"sortable":true, "search":true, "editable":false, "hidden":false, name: 'Contact', editrules:{}, addrules:{}, searchoptions: {sopt: ['cn','nc'], searchhidden:true,hidden:false} , width: 50},     
     {"sortable":true, "search":true, "editable":false, "hidden":false, name: 'Broker', editrules:{}, addrules:{}, searchoptions: {sopt: ['cn','nc'], searchhidden:true,hidden:false,dataInit:function(a){Common.setAutoComplete($(a),'/Brokers/GetBrokersByNameForAutoComplete',false);}} , width: 90}],

onSelectRow: function(id){

                        window.location = '/Issuer/' + id ;      

                    },

     multiselect: false,    
     pager: $('#IssuerListPager'),
     editurl:        '',    
     rowNum: 20,    
     pgbuttons: false,    
     pginput: false,    
     rowList: [],    
     scrollRows: true,    
     scroll: 1,    
     recordtext: "{2} Records",    
     rowNumbers: false,    
     sortname:   '',    
     sortorder: "asc",    
     hiddengrid: false,    
     caption:    '',    
     subGrid: false,    
     toppager: false,
     height: 400,   
     shrinkToFit: true,
     autowidth: true,
     viewrecords: true,
     altClass:   'altRow',
     altRows: true,

  loadComplete: function (data) { $('#IssuerListTable').trigger('jqGrid_loadComplete_ongrid', data); return; },

     gridComplete: function() { $(document).trigger('jqGrid_gridComplete');$('#IssuerListTable').trigger('jqGrid_gridComplete_ongrid');Pfc.Common.DisplaySearchDataInPager('IssuerListTable','IssuerListPager',IssuerListTablehasDefaultFilter); return; },

     beforeRequest: function() { var event = $.Event('jqGrid_beforeRequest'); $('#IssuerListTable').trigger(event); return !event.isDefaultPrevented(); },

     beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {  var event = jQuery.Event('jqGrid_beforeSelectRow'); $('#IssuerListTable').trigger(event, [rowid, e]); return !event.isDefaultPrevented(); },

     onSelectAll: function(rowids, status) { $('#IssuerListTable').trigger('jqGrid_onSelectAll', [status, rowids]); },

     });

     $('#IssuerListTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#IssuerListPager', {edit:false, edittext:'Edit', add:false, addtext:'Add', del:false, deltext:'Delete', search:true, searchtext:'Search', view:false}, {/**/ }, {/*Add*/beforeShowForm:function(){} }, {reloadAfterSubmit:true, mtype:'POST', url:''}, { search:true, groupOps: [ { op: "AND", text: "any"} ],  searchtext: 'Search',  caption: "Search Issuers",  Reset: "Clear",  closeAfterSearch: true,  closeOnEscape: true,  multipleSearch: true }, {/*view*/});$('#IssuerListTable').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#IssuerListPager', {position:'first', caption:'Add', buttonicon:'ui-icon-plus', onClickButton: function(){$(location).attr('href', '/Issuer/Add')}});

     });

</script>
```

Thank you.